# How to send input request in XML API?

Tags: java, xml

I am writing XMLAPI and passing request which is in XML to get the response in XML .

Here is the input request I am passing

```
<ASBMessage version="2.0" id="[GUID]">
  <Header>
    <Endpoint>
      <ID value="ServiceMonitor"/>
    </Endpoint>
    <Context id="request"/>
    <Itinerary>
      <Endpoint uri="asb://asb.twcable.com/dsb/channel/common"/>
    </Itinerary>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <Account operation="query">
      <ID value="12345678901" ns="UCAN"/>
    </Account>
  </Body>
</ASBMessage>
```

Here is the connection I am making to XMLAPI.

```
@Component
public class DSBClient {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("DSBClient.class");
    String cookie = "";

    public String getUCanClient(String ucanRequestStr) {
        log.info("Entering getUCanClient ..." + ucanRequestStr);
        String msg = "";
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(ApplicationPropertyReader.dsbUrl);
            bytes = ucanRequestStr.getBytes();
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bytes.length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);

            connection.connect();

            java.io.OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bytes);
            msg = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            log.info("output 3 = " + msg);
            out.close();

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            // msg = connection.getResponseMessage();

            if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                // Cookie Info might be needed , than add it - for the time being keeping blank
                log.info("Response OK");
            }
            else {
                throw new DSBException("HTTP Resonse code not OK : " + code);
            }
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        catch (ProtocolException e) {
            throw new DSBException("ProtocolException : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new DSBException("MalformedURLException : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new DSBException("IOException : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

I am getting response code "OK" but unable to get the expected response. I believe my request needs to be sent along with connection.

I am expecting to get

```
 <ASBMessage timestamp="2018-10-10T13:06:48.723" version="2.0" id="b874a232d547450c8daf14ccf54e79d8">
   <Header>
      <Endpoint>
         <ID value="DSB"/>
      </Endpoint>
      <Context id="Response"/>
      <Status id="OK"/>
      <PropertyList id="asb">
         <Property id="thread" value="8C86C9E6-A2E8-2D08-A413-A85BA14FB02C"/>
      </PropertyList>
   </Header>
   <Body items="1">
      <Account status="ok" operation="QUERY">
         <ID ns="DSB" value="624423CB-6CB3-E99D-8F1B-227289462562"/>
         <ID ns="UCAN" value="12345678901"/>
         <Status id="Active"/>
         <Audit creator="{Endpoint-Identifier}" timeCreated="181010130634518Z"/>
      </Account>
   </Body>
</ASBMessage>
```

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I am expecting to get_ The code in your question simply sends a POST request to some URL. I didn't see any code that reads from the URL. Shouldn't `connection.getInputStream()` appear somewhere in your code?

Comment: I added below lines and got the response back.

Comment: OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");    
   osw.write(ucanRequestStr);